# Determine which quadratic congruences have solutions

Tags: elementary-number-theory, congruences, quadratics, quadratic-residues

I need to determine which congruences of the form $ax^2+bx+c\equiv0\pmod{2}$ have solutions. What I know is that $a,b,c$ are all odd. I admit I have no clue how to begin on this one. This is at the end of a chapter on quadratic residues, so I'm supposed to use those to find my results. I know how to deal with stuff of the form $x^2\equiv a\pmod{p}$, but not sure how to apply that to the exercise.

Comment: Obviously $x=2$ is solution

Comment: Never underestimate the value of the common sense method...you can ALWAYS solve a congruence mod $n$ by trying every possible value $0,1,...,n-1$.

Comment: Thanks @fretty but I was looking for something more general that I could generalise to any mod, not really brute force. But ty anyways

Comment: But your question didn't ask this...it asked to solve quadratics mod $2$, so it is a case of just plugging in $0,1$ for each possible value of $a,b,c$. There is no need for fancy results (in fact most of the fancy stuff only works for odd primes anyway).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $a,b,c$ are all odd then $ax^2+bx+c \equiv x^2+x+1 \pmod 2$. Testing the two elements in $\mathbb{F}_2$, we can see there are no solutions.

Generally, for odd primes, we can use the quadratic formula since $2^{-1}$ exists modulo $p$ for odd prime. Then $ax^2+bx+c \equiv 0 \pmod p$ has a solution iff the discriminant $b^2-4ac$ is a quadratic residue.

Comment: That's what I was looking for, thanks! Just a clarification, how do I determine if $b^2-4ac$ is a quadratic residue? If I'm right $b$ is always a quadratic residue, $ac$ is a residue if both $a,c$ or neither of the two is a residue; $4ac$, if 4 is a residue; but how do I wrap the whole thing up?

Comment: This is exactly what I said in my comment, just use brute force. As for the second comment you should ask this in your question if you want a general method for solving quadratics mod $p$. In fact haven't you just read a chapter of a book on quadratic residues so surely you should know the answer to your own question?

Comment: Yeah, but it's also the second part of his comment that I needed. The chapter focused on $x^2\equiv a \pmod{p}$ and I wasn't able to come up the general reasoning for all possible cases, so I asked for how to solve that one so that I could then apply the same line of thinking to different values of $p$, but brute force can solve stuff in mod $2$, not much in mod $1001$, or so. That's what I meant.

Comment: I don't know of any method to see if the discriminant is a QR besides just plugging in the values of a,b,c. It's much easier to deal with multiplication than addition. That's why quadratic reciprocity is so vital.